# Where can I Find XFS api

Tags: c#, c++, api, winapi, cen-xfs

I want to develop a sample XFS Application which could handle a pin pad keyboard(EPP).
So i found XFS API refrence form [Here](http://www.cen.eu/cen/Sectors/Sectors/ISSS/CEN%20Workshop%20Agreements/Pages/CWA15748.aspx) but still don't know where can i find these API.
I'll appreciate who can help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just started the process of writing a wrapper for XFS in C# for a Wincor Nixdorf Cineo T2000 self-service terminal that will handle the functions for Card Reader, PinPad and Integrated Printer.

Currently, I am working for the bank that just bought the terminal, so I have access to the API, the physical device and the documentation (which is the same you are pointing out). Sadly, the XFS Standard is not a public standard as it is exclusive for the use of financial institutions, thus, you can't just, let’s say, "download" the API or the DLLs. It comes with the terminal and it is installed via its installation CDs. Even if you had the installers, based on what our provider said, you can’t install the API in a common PC because it would try to communicate with the hardware during installation and fail if it doesn’t found it.
Check out this link, maybe in the near future this company would be providing an XFS simulator (have to buy it though):

http://software-industries.com/products-xfs_simulator.htm

You asked this question several months ago, so I hope this information is useful in anyway. Cheers.

Comment: thank you for your help but I've posted this 6 month ago and now i have some good accomplishment in this field as this: I've found the XFS SDK, I tried to write a wrapper in C# directly by handling the XFS DLL in C# but with some try if figured out that there's some important issues which denies the developers to doing that. you have to deal with memory marshaling to calling XFS APIs in C# and somewhere it's so hard to handle it.

Comment: if figured out that there's some important issues which denies the developers to doing that. you have to deal with memory marshaling to calling XFS APIs in C# and somewhere it's so hard and even seems impossible to handle it. at the end i decided to write an Activex in MFC and use it in C# and other languages so I did that and now I've developed three Activexs for PIN,IDC and PTR.

Comment: I am a new "active" member of SO, and searching for information about XFS I met this question you made. I did not thought my answer would be really helpful to you due to the time elapsed since you posted the question but I thought that maybe it would help somebody else who could be looking for information about XFS. Later on, I also met other questions from you regarding XFS and I could see you had a very interesting progress with the C# wrapper.

Comment: I have posted [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771320/fill-struct-from-intptr-received-in-lparam-property-of-window-message-going-acro) on the most complicated issue I have encountered so far. I do not know if you came across the same problem or if it was something else that made you switch to ActiveX.

Comment: I knew ActiveX was a feasible solution before going for C# wrapper, but the company I am working for demanded a different solution. That is why I have been trying to get over this problem. Thanks a lot for the feedback on the answer! Cheers!